# Trying to get event channel_name_change

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to get the event `channel_name_change`. The docs look like i can call the on_message event and compare the `message.type` to `discord.MessageType.channel_name_change`.  However, when updating a channel name, the event isn't being called. I know im doing something dumb, but i cant really figure it out.  Code below

```
class channelUpdateCog(commands.Cog, name="channelUpdate"):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.type == discord.MessageType.channel_name_change:
            print("name change")
        else:
            print(message.type)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(channelUpdateCog(bot))
```

Comment: Take a look at [`on_guild_channel_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_guild_channel_update)

Comment: Yep that did it. not sure how i didnt find that. if you want to make that comment an answer, I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`on_message` is the wrong event. It will receive messages that are sent by members, not API "messages".

`on_guild_channel_update` is the correct event. It will only be called when a server channel is changed in some way. Take a look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_guild_channel_update).

You should also take a look at the list of possible events you can use [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#event-reference)